# How can I create a mutable time function where I can choose the time in python (i.e. not the actual current time)?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have an end of course Python project where I am creating a routing system in Python. I've created a menu and one of my menu options is to change the time and show the status of my packages. For example, the starting time is 8am and no packages are delivered because the trucks are just now leaving. I call my menu option to move forward one hour and the time is now 9am and I want to reprint the status of all my packages at that time. Since each package is actually being delivered at a certain time based on my algorithm, it has to actually be workable and I haven't been able to make that happen.

I know I can use datetime.now to show the current time, but I'm having trouble finding resources on how to show the time I want to be shown at the start of the program (8AM) and how to modify it where I can move it forward 1 hour multiple times.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now)
```

The above is what I've been using temporarily as a placeholder, but it doesn't correspond with the times in my package system so it's not very helpful. I appreciate any resources or nudges in the right direction!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can [`.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) a `date` and `time` into a `datetime`, so if you wanted e.g. *"today at 8am"* you could do:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> first_thing = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(8))
                                  # ^ today       ^ at 8am
>>> first_thing
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 8, 0)
```

When you want to e.g. move that forward an hour, you can use a `timedelta`:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> first_thing + timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 9, 0)
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks so much for your help!